# Discord.py - Issue iterating over member roles

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to iterate over all members on a discord server. While doing that, I want to look for members that have a specific role and write to an excel file using: `writer.writerow([members.name, members.id, members.joined_at, 'ASSIGNED'])`, otherwise write using: `writer.writerow([members.name, members.id, members.joined_at])`.

Currently, I am able to do that, however, it is writing the same user multiple times (depending on how many roles they have assigned - if they have 3, the same user's information is written 3 times). Any advice on how to write a user's info *once*?

Running the most recent version of Python and Discord.py.

```
import discord
import csv

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    guild = client.get_guild(guild_id)

    with open('joindate.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        
        for members in guild.members:
            for role in members.roles:
                if role.id == 934989847247085568:
                    writer.writerow([members.name,members.id,members.joined_at, 'ASSIGNED'])
                else:
                    writer.writerow([members.name,members.id,members.joined_at])
       
            
client.run('token')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of iterating over all of the user's roles, you can use [`discord.utils.get()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=utils%20get#discord.utils.get) to get your role and then check if the user has it. This way you will avoid looping through all roles and writing one user multiple times.

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    guild = client.get_guild(guild_id)
    specific_role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=934989847247085568) # the role id you are looking for

    with open('joindate.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        
        for members in guild.members:
            if specific_role in members.roles: # if the user has the role
                writer.writerow([members.name, members.id, members.joined_at, 'ASSIGNED'])
            else: # otherwise
                writer.writerow([members.name, members.id, members.joined_at])
```